# C# selenium chromedriver authenticating a proxy

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy

The following C# is meant to open a selenium driver and connect to a proxy with authentication. The chrome alert pops up on driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(...) and cannot get past. This means I can't deal with the alert in the try{}catch{}.

How can I authenticate the proxy?

The closest I've found so far has been [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51465053/5050423)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace ConnectProxy
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {

            var proxy = new
            {
                Ip = "XXX",
                Username = "YYY",
                Password = "ZZZ",
                Port = "80"
            };

            string PROXY = proxy.Ip + ":" + proxy.Port;

            Proxy pro = new Proxy();
            pro.HttpProxy = PROXY;
            pro.FtpProxy = PROXY;
            pro.SslProxy = PROXY;

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.Proxy = pro;

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://" + proxy.Username + ":" + proxy.Password + "@" + "whatismyipaddress.com/");

            try
            {

                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
                wait.Until(c => c.FindElement(By.Id("content-section")));

                IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials(proxy.Username, proxy.Password);
                alert.Accept();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [selenium documents](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy), attempting to do it through selenium is not an available resource. Instead, as per [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35293222/5050423), you need to add an extension to chrome with the proxy host and authentication details within it.